# Как сделать сортировку ul li через js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть сгенерированный список ul/li через php , и мне необходимо поменять местами li .
То-есть li с классом lang-item-5 сделать первым по списку, lang-item-10 вторым, lang-item-2 третьим

Сейчас список выглядит так:

```
<ul>
  <li class="lang-item-2"></li>
  <li class="lang-item-5"></li>
  <li class="lang-item-10"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> li с классом lang-item-5 сделать первым по списку, lang-item-10 вторым, lang-item-2 третьим

Можно такое сделать вот так...

```js
const o = document.querySelector('.lang-item-2')
o.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', o)
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="lang-item-2">2</li>
  <li class="lang-item-5">5</li>
  <li class="lang-item-10">10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает!